# "missing 2 required positional arguments 'headerref' and 'vertexcount'"

Tags: modeling, import

I have 0 experience with modeling or using Blender, but I am interested enough to start learning and to mess around with models to input into various games. Currently I am having trouble importing a model from Monster Hunter World (MOD3 file) and I am receiving this error message:

"missing 2 required positional arguments 'headerref' and 'vertexcount'"

I've been searching for a solution myself for hours but with no luck :(

Thanks--any help would be greatly appreciated :D

[Image of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjNUA.jpg)

edit: here is the MOD3 file's download link. Exact model is found in pl>f_equip>pl074_0000>body>mod as f_body074_0000.mod3 (752kb)

https://www.nexusmods.com/Core/Libs/Common/Widgets/DownloadPopUp?id=5258&game_id=2531&source=ModPage

Comment: which importer are you using and can you post a link to the MOD3 file so we can replicate the issue? Do any MOD3 files work?

Comment: Yes, any other MOD3 files work--above I have included a link to the MOD3 file.

Comment: link is protected by login, sorry, but I am not going to sign up just to download that file. If other MOD3 files work then it indicates that there is a problem with the file itself. Have you tried this importer https://www.nexusmods.com/monsterhunterworld/mods/969 updated only a few months ago? It has a discord link at the bottom of the page to conact the author.